# Show that if $\gamma$ is a smooth immersion, then $\gamma'(t) \ne 0$ for all $t \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$.

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

> Let $M$ be a manifold and $\gamma: (- \varepsilon, \varepsilon) \to M$ a smooth curve. Show that if $\gamma$ is a smooth immersion, then $\gamma'(t) \ne 0$ for all $t \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$.

Suppose that $\gamma$ is a smooth immersion. This implies that $\operatorname{rank}(\gamma)= \dim(M)$ or equivalently that $d\gamma_{t_0}$ is injective for every $t_0 \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$. Now $$\gamma'(t_0)=d\gamma_{t_0} \left( \frac{d}{dt} \bigg|_{t_0}\right)$$

and I need to show that this is non-zero. Is there some linear algebra fact I'm not aware of or how can I show that this is non-zero? In local coordinates $\gamma'(t_0)$ is defined as $$\gamma'(t_0)= \frac{d\gamma^i}{dt}(t_0) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \bigg|_{\gamma(t_0)}$$ but I don't get any help from this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $d\gamma_{t_0}$ maps from the tangent space $T_{t_0}\mathbb{R}$ to the tangent space $T_{\gamma(t_0)}M$. $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t_0}$ is a nonzero element of $T_{t_0}\mathbb{R}$. An injective linear map sends nonzero elements to nonzero elements, so $d\gamma_{t_0}(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t_0})$ must be nonzero.

Comment: What makes $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t_0}$ non-zero?

Comment: If you apply it to $f(t):=t$, or to any function with nonzero derivative, the result is nonzero (i.e. there is at least one function $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t_0}(f)$ is nonzero).

Answer (score 0):

> This implies $\operatorname{rank}(\gamma)= \dim(M)$

No. If $\gamma$ is an immersion, the derivative map $\gamma'(t)$ has rank equal to the dimension of the domain for all $t.$ In this case the domain $\dim T\mathbb{R} = 1.$ If $\gamma'(t) = 0$ for some $t$, then the rank is $0$, not $1.$ So $\gamma'(t) = 0$ cannot happen.